# Talend: use Maven Dependency in a routine

Tags: maven, talend

I am writing my own routine in `Talend Open Studio` to do a specific task that requires the help of a `maven` dependency.

I added the dependency to the `pom` by going to the `Project Settings` > `Build` > `Maven` > `Default` > `Project`.

However, when trying to import it into the routine, it is not found.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found of importing a library into Talend is by downloading the jar and using tLibraryLoad component to load it.

[image]

You can then add your imports in the advanced settings or using the full name of the classes.